# Aws MediaConvert terraform creation failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create an aws_media_convert_queue using terraform. Reference is taken from https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/media_convert_queue.html

```
resource "aws_media_convert_queue" "example" {
  name = "tf-test-queue"
}
```

But during resources creation I get the following error:

```
Error: Error getting Media Convert Account Client: error describing MediaConvert Endpoints: AccessDeniedException: 
    status code: 403, request id: f0742c61-f682-4986-9b60-1e1a0282f076

  on media_convert.tf line 1, in resource "aws_media_convert_queue" "example":
   1: resource "aws_media_convert_queue" "example" {
```

Comment: What permissions do you or your role have? It says permission denied. Have you added a policy with mediaconvertActions permissions?

Comment: Thank you for reply seems you're right. It was permissions issue.

Comment: Can you post your answer so that others that are stuck with this issue can get unstuck?